# Overriding/Patching function from third-party module

Tags: python

I am looking for the best practice way to overwrite/patch a function that is being imported from a third-party module.  For example, in my code i am importing and using the function like so:

```
from somemodule import some_function
foo = 3
bar = 5
some_function(foo, bar)
```

I would now like to override some_function with my own function. Im my own function, i want to do some magic and then call the orignal function.

Right now, i am doing this like so:

```
from somemodule import some_function as some_function_original

def some_function(f, b):
    # do some magic
    return some_function_original(f, b)

foo = 3
bar = 5
some_function(foo, bar)
```

However, i would like to avoid the "from [..] import [..] as [..]" and keep the original function name and just overrite/patch it?

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach? It makes it very clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider only import the namespace of the module instead of the exact function?

```
import somemodule

def some_function(f, b):
    # do some magic
    return somemodule.some_function(f, b)

foo = 3
bar = 5
some_function(foo, bar)
```